# How to make the drawer appear only on private routes?

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a system with a login, and I want the drawer to appear only on routes that are private. How can I do that, below is a code that I already tried and was not successful.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Login from "./Login";
import Details from "./Details";
import { AuthProvider } from "./Auth";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

import Drawer from "./components/Drawer";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Router>
      <Router>
        <RoutePrivate />
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

const RoutePrivate = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Drawer />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/:id" component={Details} />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do conditional rendering of drawer

```
const RoutePrivate = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
        {window.location.pathname !== '/login' ? <Drawer /> : null}
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/:id" component={Details} />
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can go with few options.

1. you can remove `<Drawer />` from router and render it inside `<PrivateRoute />` along with matched router component (Home or Details etc).
2. Inside `Drawer` component, you can check auth and render null if auth failed. This way public routes will never get to see Drawer compoennt.
3. create a common layout and put the router inside layout. Check [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-build-reusable-layouts-in-react-js-daf8adcbca79). Also I got a random [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/amanda-rhodes/son-react-admin-template?file=/src/App.js) (not fully working) but you can see the code reference there.